# Derivative of trace of matrix product including inverse

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A,B,X$ be n-by-n matrices, $X$ is nonsingular so $X^{-1}$ exist.

What will $\frac{\partial Tr(XAX^{-1}B)} {\partial X}$ be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) or [the matrix cookbook](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf), we have

$$
\def\Tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
\frac{\partial \Tr\left(X^{-1}M\right)}{\partial X}=-\left(X^{-1}MX^{-1}\right)^\top\;,
$$

so

$$
\frac{\partial\Tr\left(XAX^{-1}B\right)}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial\Tr\left(X^{-1}BXA\right)}{\partial X}=\left(AX^{-1}B\right)^\top-\left(X^{-1}BXAX^{-1}\right)^\top\;.
$$

Note that at $X=I$ this is the transpose of the commutator $AB-BA$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you do matrix derivative of Trace? I have read the matrix cookbook but I don't really get what "scalar derivative" means. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, if the matrix $Q$ is othogonal, i.e. $Q^T=Q^{-1}$, from matrix cookbook we have $\frac{\partial Q^TBQA}{\partial Q} = BQA+B^TQA^T$. Yet by plugging $Q^T$ into $Q^{-1}$ we cant yield the same formulation. Is there any problem on directly plugging  $Q^T$ into $Q^{-1}$?

Comment: Correction: Should be $\frac {\partial Tr(Q^TBQA)} {\partial Q}$